# How to obtain residuals from ARFIMA model fit with fracdiff package?

Tags: r, time-series

There is no built in method to obtain residuals from a fractionally differenced time series model fit with `fracdiff`. Does anyone have a way to do this?

```
library(fracdiff)
library(astsa)
arf.fd <- fracdiff(arf,nar=1)
resid(arf.fd)
Error: 'residuals.fracdiff' is not implemented yet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `forecast` package which has a `residuals.fracdiff` function.

```
library(fracdiff)
library(astsa)
library(forecast)
arf.fd <- fracdiff(arf,nar=1)
plot(resid(arf.fd))
```

[image]